# Javascript listen for 2nd click

Tags: javascript

I have a script which I am using.I would like it so when user clicks once it changes a var to 0 when user clicks again it changes var to 3 and then repeats. So click again would be 0 another would be 3 at the moment the part I want to detect 2nd click is 'mousemove'.Can anybody help please below is my code.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    function go() {
        i = i < height ? i + step : 1;
        m.style.marginTop = -i + 'px';
    }
    var i = 0,
        step = 3,
        space = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    var m = document.getElementById('marquee');
    var t = m.innerHTML;
    m.innerHTML = t + space;
    m.style.position = 'absolute';
    var height = (m.clientHeight + 1);
    m.style.position = '';
    m.innerHTML = t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space;
 // first click
 m.addEventListener('click', function () {
        step = 0;
    }, true);
    // second click
    m.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
        step = 3;
    }, true);

    var x = setInterval(go, 50);
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to set up a click counter. If the click counter is even then set step to zero, if odd then set it to 3.

```
  var clickCounter = 0;

  m.addEventListener('click', function () {
        step = (clickCounter++ % 2 === 0 ? 3 : 0);
  }, true);
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/byrkfvvk/**

Another approach is to have an internal property which you use as a boolean toggle.

```
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
      this.active = !this.active;
      step = (this.active ? 3 : 0);
  }, true);
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/h8hu4sm0/1/**

Comment: Thankyou very much moogs worked perfectly :) ill mark you as correct soon as can isn't letting me atm

Comment: Also if you can help further? if you notice with this [link](http://rbgraphix.co.uk/feedback.php) when I scroll down/up the page using the arrow keys I get a white flash on the last or first div depending what way I go is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @RicPurcell I don't notice the white flash

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if you want to alternate between `0` and `3` on each click:

```js
var result = document.querySelector('#result')
var step = 0
document.querySelector('#m').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  // `0` is false-y in JS, so if `step === 0`, then it'll be set to 3
  // otherwise, it'll be set to 0 (`3` is truth-y)
  step = step ? 0 : 3
  result.innerHTML = 'step is ' + step
  
  // if you want to do something with `step`:
  if (step === 0) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
})
```

```html
<button id='m'>click me</button>
<p id='result'></p>
```

Comment: basicly wat happens is when its clicken once it pauses I want it so when they click again it restarts and they can pause again if needed

Comment: @RicPurcell is this a binary decision (as in, only two options)? If so, you should just use a boolean: `var shouldDoX = true` and negate it on each click.

Comment: ye there is only 2 options pause or restart 0-stop 3-go how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @RicPurcell `var step = true` and `step = !step`. Then you can use `if (step) { /* do something */ } else { /* do something else */ }`.

Comment: don't quite understand how would implement the clicks then basically step verifies whether its paused or going

Comment: @RicPurcell instead of using `0` and `3`, use `true` and `false`.

Comment: sort of uderstnd done it like this but it only does it the first time not constant?

`if (step) {
   m.addEventListener('click', function () {
        step = false;
  
  if (!step) 
  {
   m.addEventListener('click', function () {
    step = true;
   }, true);}
   
  }, true);}`

Comment: @RicPurcell inside the event listener, use `step = !step` and `if (step) {…` instead of `if (step === 0) {…`

Comment: believe I understand now done this which works perfectly ? thankyou so much

 `m.addEventListener('click', function () {
        step = !step
  if (step) { 
   step = true;
  }
  }, true); `

Comment: the only issue now is that at top and bottom I want a margin or padding of 10px so it doesn't look like its going straight though the top and bottom of the main  div I have tried applying these to the marquee and main  div directly but doesn't work

Comment: @RicPurcell you don't need to have `step = true` inside the if statement.

Comment: ah ok so like this instead in that case I done need the if statement either correct? 

`m.addEventListener('click', function () {
        step = !step
  }, true);`